# sed replace characters in capture group

Tags: sed, regular-expression, windows, git

I've got this, which *almost* does what I want

```
git show-branch --current $SHA1 \
  | sed --quiet --regexp-extended \
    's/^.*\* \[[a-z]+\/(B-[0-9]+)-([a-z0-9-]+)\].*/\1 \2/p' \
  | sed --quiet 2p
```

and outputs

```
B-47120 java-11-take2
```

`git show-branch` is outputting this

```
! [62cba3e2b3ba8e1115bceba0179fea6c569d9274] B-48141 remove env prefix
 * [ccushing/B-47120-java-11-take2] B-48141 remove env prefix
--
 * [ccushing/B-47120-java-11-take2] B-48141 remove env prefix
+* [62cba3e2b3ba8e1115bceba0179fea6c569d9274] B-48141 remove env prefix
```

the output I would like is

```
B-47120 java 11 take2
```

which is replacing the `-`'s in the second capture group, but I can't reason a way to replace the `-` only in the second piece as I have to capture it as well.

I am on **git for windows**, and am limited to tools provided with that. although there are probably more programmatic ways to do it (I could use Perl). I would like to see a `sed` answer if possible.

**UPDATE**

because apparently this isn't obvious. The pattern is essentially `username/ticketid-description` (minus what it takes to get that from the `git show-branch`).

- username should always be alpha
- ticketid is always in format of `B-\d+`
- the description (the `\2` can have an arbitrary number of `-` that should be converted to spaces

I'm trying to programmatically turn it into a git header line for a `prepare-commit-msg` `git` hook.

Answer (score 2):

Try as follwing:

```
... |sed -nE '/^[[:blank:]*]+\[[^/]*\/(B-[0-9]+)-([^]]*)\].*/{
             s//\1 \2/; :a s/(B-[0-9]+ [^-]*)-(.*)/\1 \2/;ta; p; }'
```

Tips:

- `[^X]*`: matches any character but not character `X` (and also `\n`ewline exceptionally).
- `[^X]*X`: matches any character but not character `X` (and also `\n`ewline exceptionally) followed by a character `X`.
- `(...)`: captures a group match with back-references of `\1` for the first, `\2` for the second and so on (you only can up-to `\9` back-references).
- `:label s/find/replace/; t label`: jump to `label` for a successful substitution and repeat the command.

Or a bit shorter (depend on the input format):

```
... |sed -nE '/^[^/]*\/([^]]*)\].*/{
             s//\1/; :a s/(B-[0-9]+)(.*)-([^-]*)$/\1\2 \3/;ta; p; }'
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose the following, assuming a couple of things mentioned below (tell if these assumptions are wrong):

```bsh
# select the line with the slash character '/'
# replace the first '-' for other char not possible to be in the string, example '@'
# replace all '-' for spaces
# replace '@' for '-'
# capture everything between the '/' an the ']', remove everything else
$ sed -n -e '\:/:{s:-:@:;s:-: :g;s:@:-:;s:^.*/\([^]]*\).*:\1:p;q}'
B-47120 java 11 take2
```

---

`\:/:` select the lines that contain a slash `/`.

```
* [ccushing/B-47120-java-11-take2] B-48141 remove env prefix
```

`s:-:@:` substitute `-` for `@`, non greedy, so only the first.

```
* [ccushing/B@47120-java-11-take2] B-48141 remove env prefix
```

`s:-: :g` substitue `-` for blank, greedy.

```
* [ccushing/B@47120 java 11 take2] B 48141 remove env prefix
```

`s:@:-:` substitute `@` for `-`

```
* [ccushing/B-47120 java 11 take2] B 48141 remove env prefix
```

`s:^.*/\([^]]*\).*:\1:p;q` capture between `/` and `]`, removing averything else, print and quit.

```
B-47120 java 11 take2
```

Comment: works, but can you break down the syntax some more? it reads kind of weird to me.

Comment: @xenoterracide updated the answer.

Comment: thanks, what is the "\" before the first `:` at the very beginning

Comment: @xenoterracide I guess you mean the first backslash? the comment didn't render clearly. If it's that, it forces `sed` to use a different separator, in this case `:` instead of `/`, which should be escaped if not, it's just a matter of taste and/or deadability. When I see a pattern that has slashes, I tend to use it.

Comment: @xenoterracide This only matches the *first* occurrence, you need it to be the second, or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed's constructs you can get the output as shown.

Note: I didn't change your regexes just tweaked some portions.
Change the `{2}` to `{4}` if lets's say u needed the fourth match.

```
sed  --quiet --regexp-extended '
  s/^.*\* \[[a-z]+\/(B-[0-9]+)-([a-z0-9-]+)\].*/\1 \2/;T;G
  s/\n{2}$//;Ta
  s/-/ /2gp;q
  :a;z;H
' file
```